# CodeIgniter - create library or package that can be extended by other developer

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to create library or package (i don't know which on is good ) so that me/other team member can extend it and  can add their functionalists.

in general term i want to create library/package that can be extended (not use). there must be abstract class which have to be extended by other user

here my abtract class

```
abstract class BaseTable{
    abstract function createQuery();
    abstract function render();
    /*
    there are other concrete function but i did not mentioned here
    */
}
```

so the aim is to allow me or other person to extend this class.

Comment: Refer this Question


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097969/how-do-you-add-abstract-class-library-in-the-codeigniter-framework][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097969/how-do-you-add-abstract-class-library-in-the-codeigniter-framework

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter  load the library
here this tutorial will help 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: i know this manual and i also know how to create library. as i already told in post that i want to create library that can be extended by other user not to use