# Adapt abstract class in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, class

I have the following scenario:

Controller:

```
class Collect extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('phirehose');
        $this->load->library('oauthphirehose');
        $this->load->library('ghettoqueuecollector');
    }

    function index() {
        // Start streaming/collecting
    $this->ghettoqueuecollector('datos');
...
}
```

Class:
A)

```
class Ghettoqueuecollector extends Oauthphirehose {
...
}
```

B)

```
abstract class Oauthphirehose extends Phirehose {
...
}
```

C)

```
abstract class Phirehose {
...
}
```

When I try to use the controller gives this error:
"Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Phirehose"

That is lacking adapt? Codeigniter outside these classes work using require. Can I use them in CI? Thanks

Comment: Learn more about OOP, you cannot instantiate an abstract class. More info http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097969/how-do-you-add-abstract-class-library-in-the-codeigniter-framework

Comment: Sorry, I explain it incorrectly. I understand that it can not be instantiated, but as an abstract class should be adapted to operate in CI? @JozefDúc

Comment: I found more information here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097969/how-do-you-add-abstract-class-library-in-the-codeigniter-framework about your question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

`$this->load->library()` is made to include, *instantiate and configure* classes, it's not just an alias for `require()` - you can't use it in that manner.

If you need to extend an abstract class, you'll have to manually include/require it from the file that extends it, like this:

*libraries/Oauthphirehose.php:*

```
require_once __DIR__.'/Phirehose.php';

abstract class Oauthphirehose extends Phirehose {}
```

*libraries/Ghettoqueuecollector.php:*

```
require_once __DIR__.'/Oauthphirehose.php';

class Ghettoqueuecollector extends Oauthphirehose {}
```

Then you just load the one library that you actually need to instantiate:

```
$this->load->library('ghettoqueuecollector');
```